# Why is the ORDER BY DESC not working correctly?

Tags: sqlite, syntax, sql-order-by

The orderby for the following code is not working.. How come?

SELECT A.name, A1.Title, COUNT (T.TrackId) AS 'Total Number of Track', SUM(T.UnitPrice)AS 'Total Price'
FROM artists A JOIN albums A1 JOIN tracks T
ON a.ArtistId=A1.ArtistId AND A1.AlbumId=T.AlbumId
GROUP BY A1.Title
ORDER BY T.TrackId DESC

Answer (score 0):

Your current query doesn't make sense because you are telling SQLite to order using a column which does not exist after the `GROUP BY` aggregation.  If you want to order by the count, then perhaps this version is what you intend:

```sql
SELECT
    A.name,
    A1.Title,
    COUNT(T.TrackId) AS 'Total Number of Track',
    SUM(T.UnitPrice) AS 'Total Price'
FROM artists A
INNER JOIN albums A1
    ON a.ArtistId = A1.ArtistId
INNER JOIN tracks T
    ON A1.AlbumId = T.AlbumId
GROUP BY
    A.name,
    A1.Title
ORDER BY
    COUNT(T.TrackId) DESC;
```

Comment: I understand! Thank you. Is there anyway to do it, without using the count aggregation twice?

Comment: SQLite is highly likely not aggregating "twice."  Once it computes the count, it caches and reuses it later when ordering.